How do I create a fullscreen window so the task bar on the same monitor auto-hides?
I have Windows code where I put my app into fullscreen mode. Part of that involves auto-hiding the app bar when entering the mode and restoring the state of the app bar when exiting the mode. However, when finding the shell tray window that corresponds to the same monitor my app is on, even though I pass that handle via the app bar data structure and set the state to auto hide, all app bars auto hide (or show back up). I don't really like using ABM_SETSTATE. So ...
Raymond Replies
in this topic, that one should just create a full screen window and the app bar will auto hide. Currently in Chrome when I press F11, the only app bar that hides is the one on the same monitor. And, when activating another app on that monitor, the app bar shows up. So I assume Chrome does what Raymond indicates should be done. But how does one go about doing that?

My app is an MDI app and long ago when I implemented full screen I was setting the MDI client window to cover the monitor. After considering what Raymond said I have changed my approach and am first setting the application window to cover the monitor while manipulating the styles an then setting the MDI client window to cover the same area. I also change the z-order of the app and MDI windows to make sure they are on top of the app bar. May be my code before the changes but on Vista and pre Win 10/11 the manipulating to be on top of the app bar seemed less problemental. Testing seems to show I don't need to get the tray window for the monitor my app is on. HWND_TOP seems to do the trick though calling SetWindowPos with the tray window doesn't seem to make a difference.
